# removing stylesheet link with MooTools

Tags: css, mootools

I need to have a stylesheet link removed from my HTML head when the user clicks a link.  I found the following, but I need a MooTools equivalent.

To remove a stylesheet simply give it an id

```
<link href="cssFolder/sheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="sheet2">
```

And insert the following script just before  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#sheet2').remove();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('sheet2').destroy();
});
```

Information:

- [domready event](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DOMReady)
- [$](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollar)
- [Element.destroy()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3adestroy)

Comment: That removes the style sheet as I need, but now it is always removed. How do I set things up to run that script only when the link is clicked?

Comment: @DanHall then you need to add a click event to that link and put the `$(...).destroy();` in that event callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sheet = document.getElementById(sheet2)
sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet)
```